# React fetch data every time page reloads

Tags: reactjs, session, local-storage

I am making a react SPA application, atm I'm using fetch every time page loads, I would like to know if it's better to store such data(for example: user data) in Local Storage and if yes, what if some data in the backend DB changes?

Sorry if there are similar questions, I just couldn't find them,
Thanks

Comment: You can check it before the `API` call from the UI side. But if data changed on the backend DB side you need to call APIs. You can store data in `cache` from your back-end side for fast response.

Comment: May be many solution for this. I think you can mini request like CORS OPTIONS request every page load. And response of this request contain a flag that informat about should data reload? If yes then you can reload data, else you can use stored data. But it may not add performance advantage .

Comment: This is correct behavior, it should fetch fresh data with each reload, use redux to store management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store user data after fetching from server in local storage is good solution that I have used before.

**Use React-Query**

For update user data after that updated in DB I recommend using a swr approach packages like [react-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query) which sync your local data with server immediately.